# How to tag a vlan on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking

how can I tag a vlan via my lan interface on 16.04? I have created a vlan on my Mikrotik router as a test. Assigned an IP to the vlan, added the vlan to a port, added an IP address for the vlan in the address list. Now trying to ping the vlan from my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 but not really sure how I can do this?

Can anyone assist please? would really be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how I work with VLAN's on my machine. In my situation, I only need to access VLAN's when administering specific machines, so by default, the network interface runs untagged (i.e. without VLAN configuration).

I've made a little script which creates a secondary interface running on the specified VLAN:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will configure and start a virtual network interface which is a member of VLAN 2.
# TODO
# 0. Check if package 'vlan' has been installed and if not, prompt the user to do so.
# [code goes here]
# 1. Load the VLAN kernel module
sudo modprobe 8021q
# 2. Add enp1s0 to VLAN 2
sudo vconfig add enp1s0 2
# 2.1 Wait 3 seconds before bringing up enp1s0.2, otherwise enp1s0.2 will not get an IP
sleep 3
# 3. Bring up enp1s0.2 with IP address 10.0.0.2
sudo ifconfig enp1s0.2 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

NOTE: You will need to replace 'enp1s0' and the IP info to match your situation.

NOTE2: as you can see in the code, the script requires the package 'vlan' to be installed. You can do this by running:

```
apt install vlan
```

If anyone knows how to check for this dependency in the script, please let me know.

NOTE3: this script will not persistently add the network interface with VLAN access to your machine - when you reboot, it will be gone. Of course, you can always run the script again, or edit

```
 /etc/network/interfaces
```

and add it there. However, I'm running into issues when I try to do this on one of my servers (actually, I was hoping to find an answer to that issue here, but instead I only found unanswered VLAN-related questions), so that *might* not work.